# Can I specify GO build filename in a config file?

Tags: go, travis-ci

I'm trying to build a multi-dist executable using Travis CI which will put the built executables on github.

I want the name to be somename.os.arch.
When I build locally via command line, I use the `-o` param and the env vars `$GOOS` & `$GOARCH` e.g.: `go build -o somename.$GOOS.$GOARCH`

However, I cannot specify this for TravisCI using their `build_args` as other steps fail (not understanding -o flag)

Is there a Go build config file I can create to set the build output name?

Comment: No, there is not. I've never used TravisCI, but surely any CI system would be useless if you couldn't pass parameters to a command as part of the build - there must be some way. I guess barring that maybe you could wrap it in a bash script or something?

Comment: When I've used TravisCI, used a Makefile.  It worked fine

Answer (score 1):

Override [`script`](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/go#default-build-script). If you mean `gobuild_args` instead of `build_args`, it is only passed to the default command `go test ./...`, so I don't think it would work.